# Android - Trying to save to server Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a login & register for my app using Android Studio. I can go through my code quite well without any errors, but it's not saving the register details to my database for some reason.

I'm using www.one.com as my database host.

Register Script (php)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("   
myHost","myUser","mypass","myDatabaseName"); //Removed for safety purposes.

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Fetch User Data file (php)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("   
myHost","myUser","mypass","myDatabaseName"); //Removed for safety purposes.

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user["name"] = $name;
        $user["age"] = $age;
        $user["username"] = $username;
        $user["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Server Request

```
public class ServerRequest {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://www.domain.be/";

    public ServerRequest(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user,
                                          GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    /**
     * parameter sent to task upon execution progress published during
     * background computation result of the background computation
     */

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallBack;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                    + "Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            return httpRequestParams;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(null);
        }

    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallBack;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                    + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length() != 0){
                    Log.v("happened", "2");
                    String name = jObject.getString("name");
                    int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                    returnedUser = new User(name, age, user.username,
                            user.password);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Register

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, etPassword;
    Button bRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bRegister:
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

                User user = new User(name, age, username, password);
                registerUser(user);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerUser(User user) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
        serverRequest.storeUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(User returnedUser) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I did two things to make this work;

1. I used a free hosting for my database. I think my paid hosting denies php scripts on the server.
2. I changed some things in the build.gradle file.

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 21
>     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "AppID"
>         minSdkVersion 18
>         targetSdkVersion 21
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
> }
> ```

I also downloaded Android v21 and changed some of the newer elements in the app to work with the older version.